# Predicting file size after write.csv

Tags: r, filesize

Is there a method in R that (perhaps approximately) estimates the file size of a `write.csv` file (or other export commands, such as `dev.copy2pdf`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't heard of something like that, but here's an idea for estimating csv sizes, at least.

```
csvSizeEst <- function(obj, frac=0.01) {
    tf <- tempfile()
    on.exit(unlink(tf))
    n <- ceiling(nrow(obj) * frac)
    write.csv(obj[seq_len(n),], file=tf)
    1/frac * file.info(tf)$size
}

x <- data.frame(replicate(5, rnorm(500)))

## Estimated file size, based on a 1% sample (the default sample size)
csvSizeEst(x)
# [1] 50700

## Set fraction of file to 1 to get actual file size
csvSizeEst(x, frac=1)
# [1] 48904
```

Also, to get an order of magnitude sense of the observed relationship between data.frame size in R (as reported by `object.size`) and when written out as .csv files, try the following. (As a +/- representative sample, I here examine all of the data.frames shipped in the **datasets** package.)

```
oo <- ls("package:datasets")
dfs <- oo[sapply(oo, function(X) is.data.frame(get(X)))]
r <- sapply(dfs, function(X) {
         X <- get(X)
         csvSizeEst(X,1)/object.size(X)
     })
hist(r, breaks=20, col="lightgrey", xlim=c(0,1.5),
     main="Ratio of size-on-disk to object.size in R")
```

[image]

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the command creates the first 1% of the file and then multiplies this by 100 to get the file size. So this assumes that the file's rows are roughly equally distributed, or is that assumption not necessary? (Also, why `seq_len(n)` and not `1:n`?)

Comment: Yep, that's the assumption. It should hold exactly for data.frames made up of just numeric, integer, and boolean columns, and only probabilistically/statistically for character vectors. As for using `seq_len`, that's just a general programming habit I've developed, but which doesn't make any difference here. To see one case where it *does* make a difference, try this: `n <- 0; 1:n; seq_len(n)` .

Comment: Ouch! Good to know about `seq_len`